# Which object encryption options are available with Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)??

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

A. Server-side encryption using Amazon keys

B. Client-side encryption using customerˈs keys

C. Server-side encryption using customerˈs keys

D. Options A, B, and C

E. Options A and B

Comment: Side-note: This looks like a sample exam question. If you are learning AWS services hoping to pass an exam, it is much more worthwhile to research each of these options rather than just "learning the answer". I highly recommend reading the Amazon S3 user guide -- it contains a lot of valuable information!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am learning from Amazon S3 guides except that this question I noy understood at 100% and search help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the above:

A. server-side encryption with AWS keys: [SSE-S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html)
B. client-side encryption with customer keys: [S3 Encryption Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingClientSideEncryption.html) (or roll your own)
C. server-side encryption with customer keys: [SSE-C](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html)

See [S3 Features](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/).

Comment: Thanks! . . . . . . .